# What cello piano duets are good for busking

Tags: piano

I was wondering if anybody knew any good piano (keyboard) and cello duets that are good for busking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the occasion?!?!?!?!

If you both are comfortable "faking it" and keeping out of each others' way, there are hundreds of pieces you guys can jam over where the cello can take melody.  Bach has several wonderful pieces:  Arioso, Sheep May Safely Graze, Air for G String, Jesu Joy, Sleepers Awake, Cello Suite no. 1 in G.  I don't know if there are arrangements for piano and cello for any of those pieces but if the pianist has improvisational/arranging skills, you guys can make anything work. Personally I would just work off a lead sheet to force you to make the song your own.  You can even swap fours on something such as Pachelbel's Canon.  If you are slaves to notation, anything with a cantus firmus.

If you are looking for arrangements, many single movements of Bach's trio sonatas are wonderful.  There are also dozens of famous pop opera songs everyone loves such as THE PRAYER, TIME TO SAY GOODBYE, O CARO MIO BABBINO.

If you do a piano/cello search on popular websites such as IMSLP or Free-Scores ten or more pieces will pop up.